# Is it possible to use RIGHT() function on lookup arrayin excel?

Tags: excel

Current formula is

```
=INDEX('Construction Units'!$A$1:$H$25,MATCH(RIGHT($A39,3),'Construction Units'!$A$2:$A$25,0),MATCH($A$30,'Construction Units'!$A$1:$H$1,0))
```

what I need to figure if it is possible to do is

```
=INDEX('Construction Units'!$A$1:$H$25,MATCH(RIGHT($A39,3),RIGHT('Construction Units'!$A$2:$A$25,3),0),MATCH($A$30,'Construction Units'!$A$1:$H$1,0))
```

and yes I have tried the above and it doesn't work.  I am using data that comes out of a table in MySQL so the data is what it is.  It would be a ton of work to change either the table in excel or the table in MySQL.

Comment: You can use your formula as an array function, just apply it with `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wildcards:

```
=INDEX('Construction Units'!$A$1:$H$25,MATCH("*" & RIGHT($A39,3),'Construction Units'!$A$2:$A$25,0),MATCH($A$30,'Construction Units'!$A$1:$H$1,0))
```

Comment: Dude, duh; this is why you shouldn't excel when hangry.  Thanks!! accepting as soon as able.